# Writing constraint methods in clientValidation.jsp for AEM form

Tags: jsp, aem

I'm looking to implement some basic client-side validation scripts in AEM/CQ5.

I've researched the topic here as well as at https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/developing/developing-forms.html. I've followed that guide and I've been able to make constraints and look at the clientValidation.jsp and serverValidation.jsp files. However, this guide (and all other documentation Google seems to yield) gives little help with actually writing the JSPs.

I'm looking to implement stuff like "query the user's input to the constrained field, display an error message and do not submit the form if they made their username less than 6 characters.

I can code this sort of validation scheme with ease in JS/JQ, but this AEM-specific JSP system is throwing me for a loop with all its FieldHelpers and other such system-specific classes and function calls. Can anyone give me some good example code or an explanation of how to implement these things?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clientvalidation.jsp for a constraint is used to generate a snippet of javascript that will be used on the front side to validate the form field. To enable this, you do need to have client side validation enabled on the form dialog.

The reason for all of the FieldHelper utilities is just to wrap the majority of the boiler plate logic that would be needed to determine the name of the field and any associated logic that might be needed based on the type of field your using.

To see what gets generated you can look at the source of a page with form on it and search for a snippet of javascript named something like

```
function cq5forms_preCheck_defaultForm(submitid)
```

This will contain all of the logic checks for one of the forms on your page. Which is the compilation of all those clientvalidation.jsp servlets.

Here's the simplest one we've done which is an email validation

```
final String regexp = "/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.'-]+|(\"[^\"]*)\")([@]{1})[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$/"; 
final FieldDescription desc = FieldHelper.getConstraintFieldDescription(slingRequest);
FieldHelper.writeClientRegexpText(slingRequest,
    new JspSlingHttpServletResponseWrapper(pageContext), desc, regexp);
```

On the client side this becomes

```
if (!cq5forms_isEmpty(document.forms["form_identifier"].elements["email"])) {
    {
        var obj = document.forms["form_identifier"].elements["email"];
        if (cq5forms_isArray(obj)) {
            for (i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                if (!cq5forms_regcheck(obj[i].value, /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.'-]+|("[^"]*)")([@]{1})[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$/)) {
                    cq5forms_showMsg('form_identifier', 'email', 'Field is not valid.', i);
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (!cq5forms_regcheck(obj.value, /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.'-]+|("[^"]*)")([@]{1})[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)*(\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$/)) {
                cq5forms_showMsg('form_identifier', 'email', 'Field is not valid.');
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I believe it's the FieldHelper which goes out and validates the form field name and the constraint message and builds out that code. Although you could certainly test the output of the clientvalidation.jsp now that you know what it's doing.

As a note, there is also a servervalidation.jsp which needs to be written to validate the form value on the server side. This could be a java version of what you have in the javascript or could go into much greater depths of validation as it's independent of what the clientvalidation does.

Comment: Thanks! Also, what is the listener/event that calls the above code (and can it be changed)?